# return the sum of all characters in a row to another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this dataframe **df**:

```
column1      column2                                            column3
amsterdam    school yeah right backtic escapes sport swimming   2016
rotterdam    nope yeah                                          2012
thehague     i now i can fly no you cannot swimming rope        2010
amsterdam    sport cycling in the winter makes me               2019
```

How do I get the sum of all characters (exclude white-space) of each row in **column2** and return it to new **column4** like this:

```
column1      column2                                            column3    column4
amsterdam    school yeah right backtic escapes sport swimming   2016       70
rotterdam    nope yeah                                          2012       8
thehague     i now i can fly no you cannot swimming rope        2010       65
amsterdam    sport cycling in the winter makes me               2019       55
```

I tried this code but so far in return I got the sum of all characters of every row in column2:

```
df['column4'] = sum(list(map(lambda x : sum(len(y) for y in x.split()), df['column2'])))
```

so currently my **df** look like this:

```
column1      column2                                            column3    column4
amsterdam    school yeah right backtic escapes sport swimming   2016          250
rotterdam    nope yeah                                          2012           250
thehague     i now i can fly no you cannot swimming rope        2010           250
amsterdam    sport cycling in the winter makes me               2019           250
```

anybody have idea?

Comment: you might want to change the expected output as it is misleading. Doesn't seem correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with your solution:

```
df['column4'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda x: sum(len(y) for y in x.split()))
```

Or get count of all values and subtract count of whitespaces by [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df['column4'] = df['column2'].str.len().sub(df['column2'].str.count(' '))
#rewritten to custom functon
#df['column4'] = df['column2'].map(lambda x: len(x) - x.count(' '))
print (df)
     column1                                           column2  column3  \
0  amsterdam  school yeah right backtic escapes sport swimming     2016   
1  rotterdam                                         nope yeah     2012   
2   thehague       i now i can fly no you cannot swimming rope     2010   
3  amsterdam              sport cycling in the winter makes me     2019   

   column4  
0       42  
1        8  
2       34  
3       30
```

Comment: the second one is quite smart :) +1

Comment: works like a charm @jezrael. thank you.
Any interesting link so that I can read and dive more into lambda in python? thank you again

Comment: @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani - You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

Comment: @jezrael you can make it even simpler. check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi This works for me,

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['Stack Overflow','The Guy']})
df['Count Of Chars']=df['col1'].str.replace(" ","").apply(len)
df
```

**Output**

```
    col1    Count Of characters
0   Stack Overflow  13
1   The Guy          6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `count` with a regular expression pattern:

```
df['column2'].str.count(pat='\w')
```

Output:

```
0    42
1     8
2    34
3    30
Name: column2, dtype: int64
```

​